# Remove tags with Simple HTML DOM parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom

php code:

```
    $result = array();
    $html = file_get_html('http://site.com'.$_POST['link'].'');
    $content = $html->find('#details');
    foreach($content as $value) {
        $result['example'] = $value->outertext; 
    }
```

HTML (for parser):

```
<div id="details">
    <li>test</li>
    <tr>
        test
        <tr>test</tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>test2</tr>
    <tr>test2</tr>
</div>
```

I need to delete the last two elements "tr". How do I do this using html dom parser?

```
    <tr>test2</tr>
    <tr>test2</tr>
```

Sorry for my bad English and thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not really understand how to do it. ;{

Comment: Mixed html tags div/li/tr/no td

Comment: @10minute **What/Which part** don't you understand?